# Seeing the change of basis term $S_{ij}$ in $\mathbf e'_j = S_{ij} \mathbf e_i$ as a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[In Riley, Hobson and Bence, 3rd] A new basis $\mathbf e'_i, i=1,2,3$ is introduced, which is related to the old basis by
$$
\mathbf e'_j = S_{ij}\mathbf e_i\ ,
$$
using the Einstein summation convention.

How would one visualize $S_{ij}$ as a matrix?

My approach in deriving the term was as follows.

---

Let us denote the bases$\{\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3\}$ and $\{\mathbf e'_1,\mathbf e'_2,\mathbf e'_3\}$ by $U$ and $W$, respectively. Let $E$ be the standard basis.

Let $M_u$ be the basis matrix, having the vectors in basis $U$ as column vectors.

Now, we have $\mathbf e_j' = (\mathbf e'_j)_E = M_u \mathbf x_u = x_i \mathbf e_i $. From this, we recognize that the components $x_i$ play a special role. We can derive these by noticing that
$$\mathbf x_u = M^{-1}_u(\mathbf e'_j)_E = (\mathbf e'_j)_u\ .$$

Hence, we can now write $x_{ij} = [(\mathbf e'_j)_u]_i \ .$ This is our $S_{ij}$.

### So, we have $$\mathbf e'_j  = S_{ij} \mathbf e_i = [(\mathbf e'_j)_u]_i \mathbf e_i \ .$$

---

I'm having a hard time visualizing this $S_{ij} = [(\mathbf e'_j)_u]_i$ term, as a matrix.

Conversely, when one considers how the components of a vector $\mathbf x_E$ transforms, then it is readily apparent how $S$ acts as a matrix:
$$
\mathbf x_E = x_i\mathbf e_i = x'_j \mathbf e'_j = x'_j S_{ij}\mathbf e_i \implies x_i = S_{ij}x'_j\ .
$$
Or $\mathbf x_u = S \mathbf x_w$.

Why does this $S_{ij}$ behave as a matrix when transforming a regular vector, but not so when transforming basis vectors $\mathbf e_i$?

How does $\mathbf e_j' = S_{ij}\mathbf e_i$ relate to $x_i = S_{ij}x'_j$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The misunderstanding stems from assuming $\{\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2, \mathbf e_3\}$ is not the standard basis. This will be clear later in the post.

Let us take a step back and look at how the change of basis matrix is constructed.

Put three bases: (standard) $E=(\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3)$, $A=(\mathbf a_1, \mathbf a_2, \mathbf a_3)$ and $B=(\mathbf b_1,\mathbf b_2,\mathbf b_3)$.

Let $M_A$ and $M_B$ be the matrices having the vectors in the bases $A$ and $B$ as columns, respectively.

We have $M_A = \begin{pmatrix} \mid&\mid&\mid \\ (\mathbf a_1)_E&(\mathbf a_2)_E&(\mathbf a_3)_E\\ \mid&\mid&\mid  \end{pmatrix}$ and $M_A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} \mid&\mid&\mid \\ (\mathbf e_1)_A&(\mathbf e_2)_A&(\mathbf e_3)_A\\ \mid&\mid&\mid  \end{pmatrix}$.

$M_A$ is the change of basis matrix from basis $A$ to the standard basis $E$. $M_A^{-1}$, from $E$ to $A$. Similarly for $M_B$.

### Excursion.

We can now construct the change of basis matrix $C_{A,B}$  that is from $A$ to $B$ by $$M_B^{-1}M_A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\mid&\mid&\mid\\(\mathbf a_1)_B&(\mathbf a_2)_B&(\mathbf a_3)_B\\ \mid&\mid&\mid
\end{pmatrix}\ .$$

This can be seen as follows.

Write $[M_B|\mathbf a_j]$, as the augemented matrix. In row reduced form, we have  $[M_B|(\mathbf a_j)_A] \sim [I|\mathbf c_j]$. Or $M_B \mathbf c_j = \mathbf a_j.$ Note that $\mathbf c_j$ is the $j$th column of $C_{A,B}$, since $\mathbf c_j = (\mathbf a_j)_B$. Hence, we have $C_{A,B} = M_B^{-1}M_A$.

$M_A$ decomposes a vector relative to $A$ in terms of its standard basis components. $M_B^{-1}$ decomposes a vector relative to the standard basis in terms of its $B$ components. Hence, we get $$M^{-1}_B M_A \mathbf a = a_i M_B^{-1}M_A\mathbf a_i = a_i M_B^{-1} S_{ji}\mathbf e_j = a_i S_{ji} M_B^{-1} \mathbf e_j = a_i S_{ji} R_{kj}\mathbf b_k\ . $$

### Now, where does $\mathbf e'_j = S_{ij}\mathbf e_i$ arise?

In the text, $\mathbf e_i$ is assumed to be the standard basis. Let $A$ be the standard basis $\{\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3\}$ and $B = \{\mathbf e'_1, \mathbf e'_2, \mathbf e'_3 \}$.

How does one represent the $j$th basis vector $\mathbf e'_j$ of $B$ in terms of the basis $A$?

Well, it is represented by $M_B$'s column vectors, weighted by the basis vectors of $A$.

For $\mathbf e'_1$, we have
$$
\mathbf e'_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \mid&\mid&\mid \\ (\mathbf e'_1)_E&(\mathbf e'_2)_E&(\mathbf e'_3)_E\\ \mid&\mid&\mid  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}_B = (M_B)_{i1} \mathbf e_i
$$

### This can be written as $\mathbf e'_j = S_{ij}\mathbf e_i$.

To put thinks more into perspective, note that if we transfrom a vector $\mathbf x$ from the standard basis $E$ to another basis $B$, we multiply $\mathbf x$ by the inverse of $S$! Remember that $S^{-1}$ has as column vectors the standard basis vectors with componenents relative to the new basis $B$.

A simple illustration is changing basis by rotation about the origin. In this case, we have
$$
S = M_B =
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos \theta&-\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mid&\mid& \\
(\mathbf b_1)_E &(\mathbf b_2)_E \\ 
\mid&\mid 
\end{pmatrix}\ .
$$

If we change basis by rotation, our new basis vectors will be rotated by an angle $\theta$ about the origin. Naturally, since the vector $\mathbf x$ is invariant under rotations, its components will need to have been *rotated* in the opposite direction, in order to keep $\mathbf x$ unchanged.

Recall that the inverse of $S$ is the matrix having as columns the standard basis vectors with components relative to the new basis $B$:
$$
S^{-1} = M_B^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\mid&\mid \\
(\mathbf e_1)_B&(\mathbf e_2)_B \\
\mid&\mid 
\end{pmatrix} \ .
$$
If we multiply this inverse matrix $S^{-1}$ by $\mathbf x$, we get new components $x'_j$ of $\mathbf x$ that are weighted by basis vectors $\mathbf b_j$:
\begin{align}
\mathbf x' &=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mid&\mid \\
(\mathbf e_1)_B&(\mathbf e_2)_B \\
\mid&\mid 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\x_2
\end{pmatrix}_{E} \\
&= x_1(\mathbf e_1)_B + x_2(\mathbf e_2)_B \\ &= x_1 (t_i\mathbf b_i) + x_2 (r_i \mathbf b_i) \\ &= x'_1 \mathbf b_1 + x'_2 \mathbf b_2 \\ &= \begin{pmatrix} x'_1 \\ x'_2 \end{pmatrix}_B \ .
\end{align}
The coefficients $t_1,t_2,r_1$ and $r_2$ act to undo the rotation of the basis vectors, since $\mathbf x$ is invariant under rotations.

Also note that by $\mathbf e'_j = S_{ij} \mathbf e_i$, we implicitly mean $\mathbf e'_j = (\mathbf e'_j)_E$. How does this relate to the expression $x_i = S_{ij}x_j$?

Well, say, we have $\mathbf x' = (1,0,0)^T_B$. Representing this is the standard basis, we have $\mathbf x' S^{-1} = x_i \mathbf e_i$. For $(1,1,0)^T_B$, we have
$\mathbf x' S^{-1} = S_{i1}^{-1} \mathbf e_i + S_{i2}^{-1} \mathbf e_i$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be illustrated in a dimension two space as
$$e'_1=S_{11}e_1+S_{21}e_2,$$
$$e'_2=S_{12}e_1+S_{22}e_2.$$
One does this way because the matrix associated to the basis change is
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}S_{11}&S_{12}\\S_{21}&S_{22}\end{array}\right].$$
Which is compatible with the basis change matrix version, being
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}S_{11}\\S_{21}\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}S_{11}&S_{12}\\S_{21}&S_{22}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right],$$
and
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}S_{12}\\S_{22}\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}S_{11}&S_{12}\\S_{21}&S_{22}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: How would one derive the matrix $S$? I don't find this answer even a bit illuminating. Why do we have $$e'_1=S_{11}e_1+S_{21}e_2,$$ and $$e'_2=S_{12}e_1+S_{22}e_2\ ?$$
What do you mean by, *Which is compatible with the basis change matrix version, being*
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}S_{11}\\S_{21}\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}S_{11}&S_{12}\\S_{21}&S_{22}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right] ?$$

Comment: 1st, one writes $e'_1, e'_2$ like that to specify a new basis, $e'_1, e'_2$ since they are another vectors in the same vector space so they must be linear combinations of an initial basis. 2nd, did you see that the columns of the multiplications have the components $S_{ij}$ of the new basis?