# Can one denote different vector spaces when one uses different bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

In a [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085997/92180) about a change of basis matrix, I want to write $M_A: A\to E$, as the map that sends a vector relative to basis $A$, $a_i\mathbf a_i$ to the same vector relative to the standard basis $e_j \mathbf e_j$, distinguising a map from the matrix of a map.

In the process I, hence, consider, in fact, two vector spaces by writing this down. One in reference to each basis.

This makes the discussion easier since I can also write down $M^{-1}_B M_A: (E \to B) \circ (A \to E) $. By which it's clear that I'm talking about the vector spaces with their respective bases. This makes it clear that the *map* $M^{-1}_B M_A$, sends the basis vector $\mathbf a_i$ to $$M^{-1}_B M_A \mathbf a_i = M^{-1}_B e_i \mathbf e_i = e_iM_B^{-1} \mathbf e_i = e_i S_{ji} \mathbf b_j\ .$$

My question is, can I technically denote different vector spaces when only the bases differ and it's in fact the same vector space for the simplicity of writing out the maps? After all, can't we just say that we're talking about vector spaces $A$, $B$ and $E$ that are isomorphic to eachother?

The most important reason is that I want to write the following clear line:

$$M^{-1}_A M_B : B \to E \to A, \mathbf b\mapsto \mathbf e= M_B\mathbf b = M_B b_i \mathbf b_i = b_i M_B \mathbf b_i= b_i S_{ji}\mathbf e_j \mapsto b_iS_{ji}R_{kj}\mathbf a_k\ .$$

Hence, we can then simply write $M_A^{-1}M_B: B \to A, \mathbf b\mapsto b_iS_{ji}\mathbf e_j \mapsto b_i S_{ji}R_{kj} \mathbf a_k\ .$

That line simplifies the whole operation a lot, since it is clear between which bases we're working: we send a coordinate vector relative to $B$ to a coordinate vector relative to $A$.

Comment: I am not sure if you *can* (denote different vector spaces) but I doubt that you *need*. It seems simpler to distinguish a vector $b$ from its representation $b_B$ (or even $\text{Rep}_B(b)$) in basis $B$.

Comment: I already do that; I wrote out the matrices in reference to their representations in their different bases. My point is that I want to speak of a map, rather than solely a matrix, to pinpoint which changes of bases we're doing. It reads cleaner/more clearly. I'm just not sure if that notation is allowed. To support my case, since the "vector spaces"  are isomorphic, why not denote different spaces, for the purpose of clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not see the point. You can consider a matrix as a map $\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, ignoring the linear structure. Otherwise, if you want to do linear algebra, this is independent of the basis. But I think you are missing the two approaches here.